# JSF commandButton not call action

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have a `jsf form` render different inputText and `commandButton` if `viewParam` mode not null. Without mode param, first button call to function when click but with mode param, button not call function. It's always submit and make a postback. I want call to function, validate and redirect back.

```
<h:form style="border-top: solid 1px #DBDBDB">
    <div class="form-group" style="width: 112px; float: left">
         Quantity:&nbsp;<h:messages class="messages"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{orderCreateBean.stringQuantity}" styleClass="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 10px" rendered="#{productBean.mode == null}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Add to Order" action="#{orderCreateBean.addProduct(productBean.pid)}" styleClass="btn btn-primary" rendered="#{productBean.mode == null}"/>

            <h:inputText value="#{orderEditBean.stringQuantity}" styleClass="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 10px" rendered="#{productBean.mode != null}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Add to Edit" action="#{orderEditBean.addSelectedProduct(productBean.pid)}" styleClass="btn btn-primary" rendered="#{productBean.mode != null}" />


     </div>

</h:form>
```

OrderEditBean.java

```
public void addSelectedProduct(int pid) {
    boolean valid = false;
    if (session.get("edit_products") != null && session.get("edit_number") != null) {
        String edit_number = session.get("edit_number").toString();
        List<OrderProductDetails> opds = (List<OrderProductDetails>) session.get("edit_products");
        if (ApplicationHelper.isInteger(stringQuantity)) {
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(stringQuantity);
            if (0 < quantity && quantity <= 10) {
                valid = true;
            }
        }

        if (!valid) {
            ApplicationHelper.addMessage("Quantity between 1 and 10");
        } else {
            OrderProductDetails opd = new OrderProductDetails();
            opd.setProductId(new Products(pid));
            opd.setQuantity(quantity);
            opds.add(opd);
            session.put("edit_products", opds);
            ApplicationHelper.addMessage("Product added!");
        }

        ApplicationHelper.redirect("client/order/edit_products.xhtml?number=" + edit_number, true);

    } else {
        ApplicationHelper.addMessage("You are not in update mode!");
        ApplicationHelper.redirect("/client/product/show.xhtml?pid=" + pid, true);
    }
}
```

OrderCreateBean.java

```
public void addProduct(int pid) {
    boolean valid = false;

    if (ApplicationHelper.isInteger(stringQuantity)) {
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(stringQuantity);
        if (0 < quantity && quantity <= 10) {
            valid = true;
        }
    }

    if (!valid) {
        ApplicationHelper.addMessage("Quantity between 1 and 10");
        ApplicationHelper.redirect("/client/product/show.xhtml?pid=" + pid, true);
        return;
    }

    session = SessionHelper.getSessionMap();
    if (session.get("order_product_details") == null) {
        List<OrderProductDetails> opds = new ArrayList<>();
        OrderProductDetails opd = new OrderProductDetails();
        opd.setProductId(new Products(pid));
        opd.setQuantity(quantity);
        opds.add(opd);
        session.put("order_product_details", opds);
    } else {
        boolean exists = false;
        List<OrderProductDetails> opds = (List<OrderProductDetails>) session.get("order_product_details");
        for (OrderProductDetails opd : opds) {
            if (opd.getProductId().getPid() == pid) {
                opd.setQuantity(opd.getQuantity() + quantity);
                exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!exists) {
            OrderProductDetails opd = new OrderProductDetails();
            opd.setProductId(new Products(pid));
            opd.setQuantity(quantity);
            opds.add(opd);
        }

        session.put("order_product_details", opds);
    }

    ApplicationHelper.addMessage("Product added!");
    ApplicationHelper.redirect("/client/order/selected_products.xhtml", true);
}
```

Comment: Where's managedbeans code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of your methods 'addSelectedProduct' and 'addProduct' is wrong.
This is what the Oracle docs says about the expression allowed inside the value attribute of an h:commandButton tag:

'The expression must evaluate to a public method that takes no parameters, and returns an Object (the toString() of which is called to derive the logical outcome) which is passed to the NavigationHandler for this application.'

So this is the way I would do it:

XHTML CODE:

```
<h:commandButton value="Add to Edit" action="{orderEditBean.addSelectedProduct}" styleClass="btn btn-primary" rendered="#{productBean.mode != null}">
    <f:param name="pid" value="#{productBean.pid}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

MANAGEDBEAN CODE:

```
    public String addProduct() {

      // retrieve the pid value
      String pid = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("pid");

      // convert pid to integer value and do all your stuff here

      return null;
    }
```

and the same holds for the first method.